# Measure density with the help of buoyancy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, density, buoyancy, fluid-statics

I am trying to derive a formula to calculate the density of a irregulary shaped object.

I can measure the (**false**) weight of the object in pure air (of known density), and the (**false**) weight of the object in water (of known density).

I cannot measure (directly) the volume of the object, nor its real weight (in vaccum).

I tried this approach:
$$G_{air} = G_{vaccum} - B_{air} $$
$$G_{water} = G_{vaccum} - B_{water} $$
where $B$ is the buoyant force.

Solving both equations for $G_{vaccum}$ gives
$$G_{vaccum} = G_{air} + B_{air}$$
$$G_{vaccum} = G_{water} + B_{water}$$
so
$$G_{air} + B_{air} = G_{water} + B_{water}$$

Because $B_{air} = \rho_{air} V g$ resp. $B_{water} = \rho_{water} V g$ and 
$$V = \frac{m_{obj}}{\rho_{obj}}$$ I can write:

$$ G_{air} - G_{water} = B_{water} - B_{air}$$
$$ G_{air} - G_{water} = Vg \left(\rho_{water} - \rho_{air}\right)$$
$$ \frac{G_{air} - G_{water}}{\rho_{water} - \rho_{air}} = \frac{m_{obj}g}{\rho_{obj}} $$

And this is where I am stuck, as I cannot measure the real weight of the object $m_{obj}$. It feels like I am missing something here ...

So, how do I solve this equation to finally get an equation for $\rho_{obj}$?
Tell me if I forgot something I could measure.

---

**Edit:** Of course I can assume that the influence of the buoyant force in air is negligible and write:
$$ m_{obj}g \approx G_{air} $$
Then I can also assume that the density of air is much less than the density of water and write:
$$ \rho_{water} - \rho_{air} \approx \rho_{water} $$
Using those two assumpions I could write:
$$ \rho_{obj} = \rho_{water} \frac{G_{air}}{G_{air} - G_{water}} $$

Can I only assume the first simplification and not the second and get a better result?

And still: How do I solve the problem without those simplifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass/volume terms can be cancelled out.

You know $G_{water}=G_w$ and $G_{air}=G_a$, $\rho_w$, $\rho_a$, and want to know $\rho$.

$$G_w=mg-\rho_w V g= Vg(\rho-\rho_w)$$
$$G_a=mg-\rho_a V g= Vg(\rho-\rho_a)$$

Dividing, $$\frac{G_w}{G_a}=\frac{\rho-\rho_w}{\rho-\rho_a}$$

You can rearrange the terms after this to get $\rho$.

Remember, when solving such equations, dividing them makes more sense than adding.